# Site with Lightning Component breaks User Locale

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force.com-sites, locale

I am trying to include a Lightning Component in a Visualforce Page that is accessed via Sites.

When previewing to page in the sandbox, it works just as expected, but when accessed through the Site, the Locale of the guest User gets ignored entirely, leading to the wrong formatting on numbers and dates.

When I tried using the same Component within a Site on a Dev-Org, this did not occur. Instead, the Locale of the guest User was used. I tested this with the following code.

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" lightningStylesheets="true" title="Simple Page">
   <apex:includeLightning />
   <div id="lightning-app" style="font-size: 1rem !important;"/>
   <script>
   $Lightning.use("c:SimpleOut", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:SimpleComp", {}, "lightning-app", function(cmp) {});
   });
   </script>
</apex:page>
```

Lightning App (SimpleOut.app):

```
<aura:application  access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
   <aura:dependency resource="c:SimpleComp"/>
</aura:application>
```

Lightning Component (SimpleComp.cmp):

```
<aura:component>
   <div>
      Country: {!$Locale.country}<br/>
      User-Country: {!$Locale.userLocaleCountry}<br/>
      Currency: {!$Locale.currencyCode}<br/>
      Decimal: {!$Locale.decimal}<br/>
      Language: {!$Locale.language}<br/>
      User-Language: {!$Locale.userLocaleLang}
   </div>
</aura:component>
```

With the same settings on the guest user (Locale: German, Language: German), I got the following locale information.

Sandbox:

```
Country: US
User-Country: 
Currency: EUR
Decimal: .
Language: en
User-Language: en
```

Dev Org:

```
Country: 
User-Country: DE
Currency: EUR
Decimal: ,
Language: de
User-Language: de
```

What might I be missing/misunderstanding, for this to happen?